# What does lea rdx,qword ptr ss:[rbp+50] mean?

Tags: disassembly, x86-64, assembly

What does the code below exactly mean?

```
lea rdx,qword ptr ss:[rbp+50]
```

I have difficulty in `rbp+50`. Is `rbp` the base pointer in the 64 bit CPU architecture? What is the base pointer refering to? how can I find out the value at `rbp+50`? what does `ss` mean? what does `qword` mean? I totally confused with these terms.

Comment: [How are the segment registers (fs, gs, cs, ss, ds, es) used in Linux?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2006/2563), [How to interpret segment register accesses on x86-64?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7844963/995714), [Meaning of CS and SS registers on x86-64 Linux in userland?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19502868/995714)

Answer (score 10):

The code means `rdx = rbp + 50`.

For the explanation, we'll go bottom up...

`qword` is 8-bytes (64 bits). It stands for quad-word, same as `dword` stands for double-word. It is the size of every `rXX` register. The `qword ptr` means that we are accessing a `qword` sized memory block (as oppised to a `byte`, `word` or `dword`).

`ss` stands for stack-segment. However, in non 16-bit systems all segments are usually mapped to 0. It is probably shown in the code as an artifact of the dis-assembly as the `rbp` register is used to point into the stack.

The `lea` commands mean load-effective-address. It does not take the value at the given address, but rather the address itself. So in pseudo code we can rewrite the entire thing as `rdx = rbp + 50`.