# What does fs register value mean in x86 application?

Tags: windows, ollydbg, x86

I know that FS points to Thread Environment Block - which is seen by the address at the right part of what OllyDbg shows:

[image: FS]

What does this value 0x53 mean? Does it have some connection with the address `0x7EFDD000`? If to change FS value to 0x63 (for example), the address to the right becomes 0:

[image: FS mod]

Likewise, if to change another segment register to 0x53, it will be also pointing to TEB:

[image: CS mod]

How should we interpret all the things?

Comment: well i wrote an answer and before i could post this thread was locked so i posted it in the referred thread you may have a look

Comment: @blabb Thank you! Your answer clarifies a lot of things. The answer is [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/15545/16505).