# What does ds mean?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x64dbg

When debugging with x64dbg I sometimes see `mov ss:[address] 0xAA`, I know that this means: move 0xAA into memory at specified address.

But what does

```
mov ds:[address] 0xAA
```

mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ds` means "data segment" register in x86 architecture, while `ss` states for "stack segment" register. You would probably want to read [link](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-are-the-segment-registers-fs-gs-cs-ss-ds-es-used-in-linux) for more comprehensive description. When you see

```
mov ds:[address], 0xAA,
```

it means "move `0xAA` to address `address` in data segment", that is segment pointed by the current value of `ds` register. Similarly with every other segment register.

In x64 architecture segment registers are ignored.